# how can i retrieve Text from Text field?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I need to verify The text after entering it in the text field. sendKeys works just fine, I m able to send it to the Text field but I can't retrieve the same value from the Text field. I have used getText() and getAttribute and also JavascriptExcutor but still doesn't work. I have provided the input HTML code below.

```
     <input type="text" id="txtAge" maxLength="3" style="width: 4em"> ==$0
   <td>
```

Comment: whats the problem with the above code?

Comment: the above code works just fine there are some categories that are not in Alphabetic order and I get an exception. I need a code to handle the categories that are not in Alphabetic order.